# Remove carriage return from text file

Tags: notepad++, notepad, csv

I have a text file that is | delimited and is over 59,000 line long.  How can I remove the carriage returns so each line is one record?

Here is what the current file looks like:-
[image]

Here is what I need it to look like:-
[image]

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `[^|\n\r]\R`
- **Replace With:** `\1`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All

It matches OS-linebreaks (`\R`) that are not (`^`) preceded by a `|` or `\r` or `\n`. Should work with any EOL convention.

Answer (score 6):

In notepad++, you can actually open the search box, check the option for "extended search" in the search mode, and replace `\R` with blanks. This will help you replace the carriage return characters...

This also works for the other special chars such as `\t`, `\n`, etc.

Comment: It's lowercase `\r` not `\R`.