# Carriage return issues when export the results into excel sheet by running the query in Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata

Good day,

I want to export the results into excel sheet by running the query in Teradata SQL Assistant. If comment column contains multiple lines, values are not correctly fall under respective column. I am getting result as follows

[Wrong Result with data having carriage return for comment columne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQXi5.png)

Required result is as follows.

[Correct Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcIYx.png)

Following is the data which I tried to export to excel from csv file(csv generated by running the query in Teradata SQL Assistant). I tried by applying regx to remove carriage return but it didn't work(reference: [Remove carriage return from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758450/remove-carriage-return-from-text-file)). Can you please guide me on this.

```
Employee|ID|Comment
Jack|22|My Feedback:  Good hotel to saty.  Nice location

Area of improvements:  Room service
Julia|35|My Feedback:  Good Rooms. Excellent place
```

Comment: You can remove the line  breaks in your Select using `RegExp_Replace(col, '[\n\r]+', ' ',1,0,'m')` or replace any whitespace with a single blank:  `RegExp_Replace(col, '\s+', ' ',1,0,'m')`

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. It worked!! Can you please explain the parameters of RegExp_Replace(col, '[\n\r]+', ' ',1,0,'m') and RegExp_Replace(col, '\s+', ' ',1,0,'m').
whether \s+ pattern remove all special characters  or just new line ?

Comment: `'\n\r'` are CRLF and `'\s'` is any whitespace, e.g. CRLF, TAB, space, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Assistant Options there is an Flag where you can instruct SQL Assistant to remove all CR/LF from Exports. I think it's easier than RegExp in SQL. ;)

(SQL Assistant) -> Tools -> Options -> Export -> "Replace Carriage Returns in column data with blanks"